# How to join product collection of magento 2 to a custom table?

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, join-table

I have a custom table `user_product_table` with a field `sku`(this field join to product collection) and `user`. How can I join this table with product collection, so that I don't have to loop my custom collection to get product in each row.

My `$userCollection`:

```
 $userCollection = $this->_userProductFactory->create()
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('user', 2);
```

My product Collection:

```
$productColelction = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','image','short_description','sku'))
```

I would like to have final collection both my custom table fields and selected product attributes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use the join like this:

```
            $joinConditions = 'u.sku = e.sku';

            $productColelction->getSelect()->join(
                ['u' => $productColelction->getTable('user_product_table')],
                $joinConditions,
                []
            );
```

Multi conditions:

```
        $joinConditions[] = "u.sku = e.sku";

        $joinConditions[] = "e.type_id= 'simple' ";

        $joinConditions = implode(
            ' AND ', $joinConditions
        );
```

Comment: Thank you,  One question what if the user_product_table contain multiple same sku's? Is it also possible to join?

Comment: Yes, it is. We can join.

Comment: how would you add a join condition that was based off a variable generated earlier, for example i have a set type_id i'm looking for each time this module runs and so my variable is called $typeid would it be "e.type_id= ' ".$typeid." ' ";

Comment: @John can you ask a new question and link to my answer for a reference? I will take a look.

Comment: i think i've found something i'll report back to you if it works

Comment: Solution found, it needs to be something like this $joinConditions[] = "c.category_id= '" . $catid . "' "; where $catid is your variable, and the c is your alias for the table. works perfectly.

Comment: '" is single quote, double quote, variable, double quote single quote double quote if that makes sense, it's important the single quotes surround the value

Comment: thanks that helps alot