# Magento 2 get Collection Data From Two different Third Party Module and Merge

Tags: magento2, collection

I have Two Module "Module A" and "Module B" ,In Module A there is a listing page where data is fetching the table by collection and listing on frontend and same doing Module B.

I want to customize Module A so that collection data modified in a way that we can merge data from Module B collection and display both table data in frontend.

Please help me what we need to do.

Comment: Join 2 collection in any one of your module. You find more information about join 2 collection here. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149080/how-to-join-product-collection-of-magento-2-to-a-custom-table

Comment: @user55548 ,thanks for your quick answer ,trying.